# Typescript split object into properties from multiple interfaces

Tags: typescript

I was wondering if it's possible to go from

```
interface AnB extends InterFaceA, InterfaceB
const aAndB: AnB = {etc etc}

back to 

const valuesFromInterfaceA = all values from aAndB that exist on InterfaceA
const valuesFromInterfaceB = all values from aAndB that exist on InterfaceB
```

Without exactly knowing what properties InterfaceA / InterfaceB provides the object.

Comment: Types do not exist at runtime, so it won't be possible

Comment: @AlekseyL. I figured, that's too bad :(

Answer (score 0):

with `import * as _ from 'lodash';` and knowing all members from each InterFaceA or InterFaceB, you can use

```
const valuesFromInterfaceA = _.pick(aAndB, 'memberFromA');
```

or

```
const valuesFromInterfaceA = _.omit(aAndB, 'memberFromB');
```

Answer (score -1):

If the intent is intellisense, since you're using typescript, you could simply assign a type to the variables, like so:

```
interface AnB extends InterFaceA, InterFaceB
const aAndB: AnB = { etc etc }

const valuesFromInterfaceA: InterFaceA = aAndB as InterFaceA
const valuesFromInterfaceB: InterFaceB = aAndB as InterFaceB
```

Comment: The intent was to split it up so I could use the spread operator and pass the result down as props (react) without having the values of the other interface be passed down too. Thanks for replying tho

Comment: @RubenHamakers I wish to do the exact same thing, it's not very DRY nor SOLID to manually extract an interface from the rest props every time... Any solution you've found?

Comment: Hi @Wolfzoon no I did not, I ended up just typing out my own interface lol.

Comment: it seems to work, but all parts do remain in the result